# File specified in both Copy Bundle Resources and Copy Files?

Tags: ios, xcode, ide, xcode6, development-environment

Do I need to specify a file both in Copy Bundle Resources and Copy Files phase? Also, while I have some understanding of what both of them is for, can someone explain in what ways these to are different and in what ways similar? Lastly, what is the meaning of the directories shown in destination and subfolder field, as for the actual paths? I thought if I put a folder to copy files phase it would ALSO create a folder in the package contents of the app but it did not.

[image]

I would appreciate if someone helps me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was not in my understanding. It is solved after I cleaned the build. As for the meaning of these directories, I have found out that "Resource" and "Wrapper" directories are just some abstract names that point to the various places within the bundle structure. Resource directory means the top level of the bundle in IOS and can mean something else in OSX. So... that was my stupid problem.